# Prove that if $f\in C([a,b])$ satisfies $\int_a^bx^kf(x)dx=0 \ \forall k\geq0$ then $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

Prove that if $f\in C([a,b])$ satisfies $\int_a^bx^kf(x)dx=0 \ \forall k\geq0$ then $f=0$. I saw this problem online and as I'm currently studying functional analysis I'm interested in a solution using this field. I proceed as follows:

Let $L:C([a,b])\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $L(x)=\int_a^bf(t)x(t)dt$. From linearity of the integral que see that $L$ is linear. Furthermore, $$|L(x)|=\bigg\vert\int_a^bf(t)x(t)dt\bigg\vert\leq\int_a^b|f(t)x(t)|dt\leq C||x||_{\infty}, \ \ C=\int_a^b|f(t)|dt$$So $L$ is continuous ($L\in (C([a,b]))^*$). By Weiertrass approximation theorem, the span of $\{x^k\}_{k\geq0}$ is dense in $C([a,b])$, and by hypothesis $L$ is identically $0$ on this set, so $L=0$ (as $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff and $L$ and the zero functional are equal on a dense set). Now use that to conclude that
$$
L(f)=\int_a^bf(t)^2dt=0
$$
and so $f=0$.
Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, your solution is flawless.

Comment: I would skip the analysis of $L.$ Just use the fact that by the Weierstrass theorem there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ such that $p_n(x)\rightrightarrows f(x)$. Therefore $p_n(x)f(x)\rightrightarrows f^2(x)$ hence $$\int p_n(x)f(x)\,dx \to \int f^2(x)\,dx$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc what do you mean by those double arrows? I have never seen that notation.

Comment: Double arrows denote the uniform convergence